# Why does "puts" return a blank line, but not "puts []"?

Tags: ruby, arrays, io, puts

I'm going through a [Ruby tutorial](http://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/?Chapter=07), and learned that the code

```
puts 'start'
puts
puts 'end'
```

will output three lines, but the following code

```
puts 'start'
puts []
puts 'end'
```

will only output two. The stated reason is that [] <strike>isn't an object</strike> (edit: "doesn't point to anything"), so `puts` can't do anything with it, but why is that not also true in the first case?

I tried to find an official page about `puts` to figure this out, and [this one](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-puts) was no help.

Comment: That is wrong. `[]` is an object.

Comment: `[]` isn't an object when you use it as `some_method[]`(no space between method and []). however in your case  it is clearly an object

Comment: @sawa, i mean `[]` and `[]=` methods

Comment: @slivu `[]` within `puts []` cannot be a method. My understanding is that `[]` needs an explicit receiver.

Comment: @sawa, sure, just seems OP confused about when `[]` used as object and  when as method.

Comment: @slivu: I think he's not. See his comment under my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The stated reason is that [] isn't an object

Stated where?

`puts` has a special handling for arrays. When you pass it an array, it prints each element on a new line. You pass it an array with zero elements, it prints zero lines.

Comment: In the tutorial: "the array doesn't point to anything, so there's nothing to `puts`."

That makes sense, thanks!

Comment: @Zach The part you cite in the tutorial is misleading. The array does point to something; it just doesn't have any element.

Comment: That makes even more sense.

Answer (score 2):

`puts` with an array will print one line per element. No element, no lines.

EDIT: What I just said is documented in your link:

> If called with an array argument, writes each element on a new line.

Comment: Yes, I should've caught that myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
puts arr
```

is like

```
arr.each { |e| puts e }
```

You can do something like this by yourself:

```
def p(s)
  if s.respond_to? 'each'
    s.each { |e| p e }
  else
    puts s
  end
end

p 'hello' # prints line with 'hello'
p [] # prints nothing
p [1, 2] # prints 2 lines with 1 and 2
```

Answer (score 2):

The link your shared, states:

> If called with an array argument, writes each element on a new line.

```
puts []
```

means, you are calling `puts` with empty array. i.e. no elements to print. and that's what happened.

Answer (score 2):

Puts with no arguments has special behaviour - i.e. print new line. In all other cases, it treats all arguments as an array, and maps these arguments to strings using #to_s, and outputs each string on a new line. That's why you get no output when calling `puts []`. If you want to have a new line in the output, you can either call `puts` with no arguments (it's obvjous), or use splat operator with empty array, like this: `puts *[]`.

You can write your own implementation of `puts` in order to understand things better.

```
  def my_puts(*args)
    STDOUT.write("args is #{args.inspect}\n")
    if args.empty?
      STDOUT.write("\n")
    else
      args.each { |arg| STDOUT.write("#{arg.to_s}\n") }
    end
  end


1.9.3p194 :039 > my_puts
args is []

 => 1 
1.9.3p194 :040 > my_puts []
args is [[]]
[]
 => [[]] 
1.9.3p194 :041 > my_puts *[]
args is []

 => 1 
1.9.3p194 :042 > my_puts 1,2,3
args is [1, 2, 3]
1
2
3
 => [1, 2, 3] 
1.9.3p194 :043 > my_puts [1,2,3]
args is [[1, 2, 3]]
[1, 2, 3]
 => [[1, 2, 3]] 
1.9.3p194 :044 > my_puts *[1,2,3]
args is [1, 2, 3]
1
2
3
 => [1, 2, 3]
```